# terminal : revert filename order

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

I have numbered images in a directory :

```
001.jpg 002.jpg 003.jpg ... 010.jpg
```

I want to rename them to the reverse order :

```
001.jpg -> 010.jpg
002.jpg -> 009.jpg
...
010.jpg -> 001.jpg
```

I had the idea to do the following

```
i=1; for f in $(ls -r *.jpg); do mv "$f" "$(printf %03d $i)".jpg; ((i++)); done
```

It will fail when renaming 005.jpg who has already been replaced.

I could do a first loop to rename them to temp001.jpg then run the loop above.  But is there a nice way to do that in one command ?

Comment: Why not do it in a script so you could use multiple steps?

Comment: As I said I could do two operations in a script, but I'm wondering if this can be done in one step.

Comment: Well it would probably be easier to make it safer with multiple steps. Less code isn't the same as better code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a script file like this.

```
n=10
for i in {1..10}
do
    let aa=n-i+1     
    cp $i.jpeg $aa.jpg
done
rm *.jpeg
mv *.jpg *.jpeg
```

Be sure to check that script works since it removes original files.